# Search all records/rows in Peewee ORM model that contain a given word in a column

Tags: python, orm, peewee, flask-peewee

I have the following peewee model:

```
class Product(peewee.Model):
    key = peewee.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = peewee.CharField(null=False)
    is_active = peewee.CharField(null=True)
    base_price = peewee.IntegerField(null=True)
```

I would like to search all Products that contains in its column "name" the word "foo".

1. Can it be done with Product.get() ?
2. Which is the right syntax to achieve it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else:

```
Product.select().where(Product.name.contains(text))
```

where *text* contains the pattern to search (case-insensitive).